# Django: Displaying formset errors correctly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have an inline formset for a model, which has a unique_together constraint. And so, when I input data, which doesn't fulfill this constraint, it displays:

**`__all__Please correct the duplicate values below.`**

The code, which does this is:

```
    {% for error in formset.errors %}
        {{ error }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
```

I don't much like the `__all__` at the beginning of the error and it is quite clearly the dictionary key, so I tried:

```
    {% for key, error in formset.errors %}
        {{ key }}: {{ error }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
```

But then all I get is:

**`__all__:`**

{{ error }} won't display at all. So what's going on here? And how do I display the error correctly?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `formset.errors` is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

From the [Django docs page on formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation):

```
>>> formset.errors
[{}, {'pub_date': [u'This field is required.']}]
```

See if something like this fixes the problem: (**Updated based on the askers comments**)

```
{% for dict in formset.errors %}
    {% for error in dict.values %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If that fails, I'd try using `manage.py shell`, and try to reproduce your situation in the python shell... that way it will be easy to inspect the various values and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks :) Helpful. Your way didn't work, but I've finally got it working with a small modification (errors.values instead of errors), so it now looks like this:
{% for dict in formset.errors %}
            {% for error in dict.values %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

Comment: Glad I could help.  I've updated my answer based on your comments.  Seems the key issue that was messing it up before was that `formset.errors` is a list of dicts, not a single dict.

Comment: For current version of django, looping over errors in templates is generally not what you want. Since the OP asked at the end "... how do I display the error correctly?", I would refer to the other answers not involving the looping over errors.

Answer (score 14):

The for loops are unnecessary, these errors should be correctly displayed with the following:

```
{{ formset.non_form_errors }}
```

Comment: This is a function not a property thus does not return the errors as you might have expected

Comment: I agree with @Paullo For some reason this way does not show some of the errors.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a clarification for anyone encountering similar issues of errors not being rendered in template:

If you have and error regarding the formset as a whole, use:

```
{{ formset.non_form_errors }}
```

this basically returns errors in `__all__` entry from `formset.errors`. It is documented as:

```
    """
    Returns an ErrorList of errors that aren't associated with a particular
    form -- i.e., from formset.clean(). Returns an empty ErrorList if there
    are none.
    """
```

However if you are rendering forms from formset and some errors are not being renderd, you are probably missing:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    {# ... #}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

this returns errors in `__all__` entry from `form.errors`. Those are, analogous to the `non_form_errors`, the errors that aren't associated with a particular field, but rather with the field relations. For example if you had a form with fields `From` and `To`, and you validate if `From` value is smaller then `To` value, the tag `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` could render the following error:

```
'The From value must be smaller than the To value'
```

Comment: If you'd like to set the formset.non_form_errors value yourself, use the following syntax `formset._non_form_errors = "my error message"`   (Notice the underscore before non_form_errors)

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.6 formsets have a new method, `BaseFormSet.total_error_count`. Using this in a template conditional ensures you only will output errors and markup if at least one error exists in the formset.

```
{% if formset.total_error_count %}
    <ul class="errorList">
    {% for dict in formset.errors %}
        {% for error in dict.values %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

See the [Django docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet.total_error_count) for v1.6+.