# Django: Change formset error message(s)

Tags: python, django

Hello fellow programmers,

I would like to change the `min_num`  error message of a formset.

My code creates a formset using an inlineformset_factory:

```
formset_clazz = inlineformset_factory(MyParentModel, MyModel, MyModelForm, can_delete=True, min_num=1, validate_min=True) 
formset = formset_clazz(data=request.POST)
print(formset._non_form_errors)
if formset.is_valid():
    print("yay!")
else:
    print("nay!")
return render(request, "mytemplate.html", {'formset':formset})
```

In the template I render the non_form_errors:

```
  {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
  <ul>
    {% for error in form.non_form_errors %}
      <li>
        {{ error }}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

The `min_num` validation works as intended and shows the error message `Please submit 1 or more forms.`, when a user removes all forms and submits the formset.

My question is: How do I change the error message?

From [0] I learned, that it is stored in `formset._non_form_errors`, but without a way to override the `too_few_forms` [1] (ctrl-F `validate_min`) code's message. The `BaseFormSet` class itself uses `ngettext` to translate the message, but I do not really want to setup internationalization just for this (or is that easy and straight-forward?).

Is there a more convenient way to achieve my goal?

[0] [Django: Displaying formset errors correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173138/django-displaying-formset-errors-correctly)

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/formsets/#BaseFormSet

Comment: I'd like to override the messages for the codes 'too_few_forms' and 'too_many_forms' as well. Relevant part is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/16ee53d7bb01819859c78a88e3fc93eda985f71a/django/forms/formsets.py#L345).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in `full_clean` method of your formset class. Not pretty, but works.

```
class CheeseStickFormset(BaseFormSet):

    def full_clean(self):
        super(CheeseStickFormset, self).full_clean()

        for error in self._non_form_errors.as_data():
            if error.code == 'too_many_forms':
                error.message = "Please eat %d or fewer cheese sticks." % self.max_num
            if error.code == 'too_few_forms':
                error.message = "Please eat at least %d cheese sticks." % self.min_num
```